# Problem using React createContext and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a simple calculator made on react + typescript using vite. It's my first time using react + typescript so I don't know the right way to use the ContextAPI. I got this error trying to build the aplication with yarn build.

```
src/components/Screen.tsx:5:11 - error TS2339: Property 'showOnScreen' does not exist on type '{}'.

const { showOnScreen, onDeleteButton } = useContext(AppContext);
```

AppContext.tsx

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const AppContext = createContext({});
```

ContextProvider.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [showOnScreen, setShowOnScreen] = useState('0');
  const [isLastAResult, setIsLastAResult] = useState(false);

  const onDeleteButton = () => {
    if (showOnScreen.length === 1 || isLastAResult) {
      setShowOnScreen('0');
      setIsLastAResult(false);
      return;
    }

    setShowOnScreen(showOnScreen.substring(0, showOnScreen.length - 1));
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        onDeleteButton,
        showOnScreen,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Screen.tsx

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '../context';

export const Screen = () => {
  const { showOnScreen, onDeleteButton } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div className='row bg-white rounded-4'>
      <div className='col-12 pe-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
        <span className='py-2 fs-4'>{showOnScreen}</span>
        <button
          className='text-danger rounded-start btn rounded-4 h-100 fs-5'
          onClick={onDeleteButton}
        >
          DEL
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, `createContext` uses generics ie it is a `createContext<T>` that automatically adapts to your type when you don't specify anything else. It propagates the type to your variable - `AppContext` which gets assigned `{}` as a type.

There are various ways to assign it a type, like:

```
export const AppContext = createContext({} as { showOnScreen?: bool; });
```

or

```
export const AppContext = createContext<{ showOnScreen?: bool; }>({});
```

or

```
interface IContext {
  showscreen?: bool;
}
export const AppContext = createContext<IContext>({});
```